# What is the difference between yoyo migrations and django migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Can someone please explain the difference between yoyo migrations and django migrations? Why can't we just use the built-in migrations in Django using `python manage.py migrate`?

I'm trying to move my Django application forward to staging but our DevOps team is saying we need a database migration tool--specifically, they recommended yoyo since it's in Python like Django. But, I'm confused as to why we need this when Django has built-in migrations. What am I missing?

Not sure if it matters, but we're using a PostgreSQL db. We have an organization-wide db and all our tables exist in a schema specific to our project.

Comment: Maybe your DevOps team doesn't know that Django already has DB migrations. I will just point the DevOps team that Django has DB migrations and if the still push for yoyo ask for clarification why, maybe the have a valid reason for there setup.

Comment: @Krukas that's what I was thinking, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a valid reason I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

it's all depends on your DevOps team, using django migration or using yoyo migrations won't be make any big difference, **Yoyo** is just a Python database schema migration tool.

You write migrations as Python scripts containing raw SQL statements or Python functions.
there is nothing that you can't do with django migrate,
but there are some benefits or we should say shortcut to do some work done faster and easily.
Yoyo is usually invoked as a **command line script** and provides a command line tool for reading a directory of such scripts and applying them to your database as required.
I suggest you to read yoyo document and when you did, you will realize why they said this to you, Again it's up to your DevOps team, I think they said this because It provides commands to manage migrate repository and database selection as well as **script versioning**.